# My responsive navigator bar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navigator

Okey so when i tried to make dropdown responsive navigatorbar but it just dosen't work so if someone could help me with this that would be nice :)

More about my issue.

So menu should open when i press this button
[picture of navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfKoL.png)

normally when i change 
  header nav ul height to 0 it closes it but when i change it to auto; it opens menu but it wont close it so i tried to make script that reads when you click that picture it will turn it to auto; but i dosen't seem to work.
so my problem is that i can't open it or close it.

fa-bars is picture from awesomefont just to make that clear.

Here some code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fa-bars").on("click", function() {
    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
/* MOBILES */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  #logo {
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  header nav {
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .fa-bars {
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin: 13px 35px 0 0;
  }
  .fa-bars:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  header nav ul {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header nav ul.open {
    height: auto;
  }
  header nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  }

  header nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script defer src="js/fontawesome.js"></script>
    <title>SeQaFin</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- NavBar -->
      <nav id="main-nav">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        <ul>
          <a href="#Kotisivu"><li>Etusivu</li></a></li>
          <a href="#Tietoa"><li>Tieto</li></a>
          <a href="#Liity"><li>Liity</li></a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Etusivu -->
    <section id="Kotisivu">
      <h3 id="seqatext">DOwn</h3>
      <a href="#Tietoa">
        <img src="img/down.png" alt="Down">
      </a>
    </section>

    <!-- Tietoa -->
    <section id="Tietoa">
      <h3>Tietoa</h3>
      <hr>
      <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
      <h4></h4>
      <p>
      </p>

      <h4></h4>
      <p>
      </p>

      <h4></h4>
      <p>
      </p>

      <h4></h4>
      <p>
      </p>
      <br><br><br><br><br>
    </section>

    <!-- Liity -->
    <section id="Liity">
      <h3>Liity</h3>
      <hr>
      <h4>Ohjeet</h4>
      <p>Ohjeet Tähän!</p>

      <form>
        <input class="input_text" type="email" tabindex="1" placeholder="Sähköposti"><br>
        <input class="input_text" type="text" tabindex="2" placeholder="Otsikko"><br>
        <textarea class="input_text" tabindex="3" placeholder="Viesti"></textarea><br>
        <input class="button" type="submit">
      </form>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <p>
      </p>
    </footer>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mobile.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've left out the HTML, which makes this question unanswerable.  Please also try to be more specific than "it just doesn't work for some reason."  What isn't working?

Comment: Fixed my post i hope its easier to read now

Comment: uh, why are you using `display:inline-block` and `float` property with your `.fa-bars` selector?

Comment: why do you have `fas fa-bars` as a class? Why not just `fa-bars`?

Comment: well it has display: inline-block because with other devices like computer you wont see that menu selector thing. Float for position. Not working with only fa-bars.

Comment: You need to pick `display:inline-block` or the `float` property. There is a way to correct the fact you cannot see the hamburger stack when applying float property. You have a lot that needs work here. Can you tell me where did you get the idea to do `<i class="fas fa-bars">`?

Comment: it's fontawesome thing to get that hamburger icon.

Comment: Okey i tried to delete display: inline-block and float it just made it worse but still can't click it.

Comment: @CrazyBeast, you really need to learn how to put together a responsive layout. You have a lot of work to do here. You don't even have `main-nav` as a selector, this is what you need to give a float to and to div with id of `logo`. These are your children and `<header>` is your parent.

Comment: Well website looks pretty good now but well i will start to recreate it. My code seems to be way too messy. Thanks for your tips @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You have not loaded your script file.

Try it with the correction I made here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fa-bars').on('click', function() {
  $('header nav ul').toggleClass('open');
 });
});
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  

#logo {
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}

header nav {
  margin: 0;
  float: none;
}

.fa-bars {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  margin: 13px 35px 0 0;
}

.fa-bars:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

header nav ul {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header nav ul.open {
  height: auto;
}

header nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script defer src="js/fontawesome.js"></script>
    <title>SeQaFin</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- NavBar -->
      <nav id="main-nav">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        <ul>
          <a href="#Kotisivu"><li>Etusivu</li></a></li>
          <a href="#Tietoa"><li>Tieto</li></a>
          <a href="#Liity"><li>Liity</li></a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Etusivu -->
    <section id="Kotisivu">
      <h3 id="seqatext">DOwn</h3>
      <a href="#Tietoa">
        <img src="img/down.png" alt="Down">
      </a>
    </section>

    <!-- Tietoa -->
    <section id="Tietoa">
      <h3>Tietoa</h3>
      <hr>
      <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
      <h4></h4>
      <p>
      </p>

      <h4></h4>
      <p>
      </p>

      <h4></h4>
      <p>
      </p>

      <h4></h4>
      <p>
      </p>
      <br><br><br><br><br>
    </section>

    <!-- Liity -->
    <section id="Liity">
      <h3>Liity</h3>
      <hr>
      <h4>Ohjeet</h4>
      <p>Ohjeet Tähän!</p>

      <form>
        <input class="input_text" type="email" tabindex="1" placeholder="Sähköposti"><br>
        <input class="input_text" type="text" tabindex="2" placeholder="Otsikko"><br>
        <textarea class="input_text" tabindex="3" placeholder="Viesti"></textarea><br>
        <input class="button" type="submit">
      </form>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <p>
      </p>
    </footer>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's that index.js?

Comment: the `index.js` has your jquery code. I also included the `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` library and also you had a closing `}` missing. so your media query was not closed.

Comment: so where was that closing thing still dosent seem to work

Comment: I think you need to be more clear where is your jquery code stored. I put it in an `index.js` file and made sure I loaded it into your html file and now the hamburger stack works, it gives me a dropdown and closes it back up and obviously you need to be pulling in a jquery library as well which I did with `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`

Comment: It should have worked then, so what does `js/jquery.js` do?

Comment: @CrazyBeast, copy what I have into your code editor and try it. Its working from my end.

Comment: js/jquery is jquery from website and its 3.3.1.min and mobile.js have  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fa-bars").on("click", function() {
    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");
  });
});               in it

Comment: It should have worked then, its working on my local environment. The same exact code I pasted as the answer with the missing `}` after your media query.

Comment: copied everything but it still dosent seem to work ?

Comment: you have it in a github repo? And can you add a screenshot of your file structure.

Comment: no i dont have it in github repo but did you mean this ?https://imgur.com/a/QNfMK

Comment: @CrazyBeast, your file structure looks okay, I don't know what to tell you at this point. It's working from my end and it should have worked for you. The only syntax error you had was in your css.

Comment: To be clear, when you click on the hamburger stack, you are expecting for a menu to dropdown with Etusivio, Tieto and Liity, correct?

Comment: That's an idea, @CrazyBeast, get rid of that file and go to jquery documentation page and download and implement this one: `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`

Comment: is any of these good?    https://imgur.com/a/mu6di    didn't find versions at documentation

Comment: okey i found it but still not working :/ now i only got hamburger thing left

Comment: yes that is the page, just click on the first link and move the `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` file from your download to your `js` folder in your project, make your you change the name in the script tag and give it a try.

Comment: I don't know what could be going on then.

Comment: i posted whole css mobiles part.